# Power of the Sand Snake girls

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

The Sand Snake girls are introduced in late 5th season of [Game of Thrones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones). The eyes of Bronn started burning when he looked at one of them.

What is the power of the Sand Snake girls?

Comment: The only special power I'm aware of them having is the power to speak terrible, terrible dialogue in a show with normally high standards

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are referring to their scene together in the prison.

The Sand Snake in question is [Tyene](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Tyene_Sand). She had cut [Bronn](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Bronn) earlier in the episode in a fight, with a dagger coated with poison (called [The Long Farewell](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Long_Farewell)).

This makes Bronn's heart rate increase, his nose bleed, **his  vision blur** and he eventually collapses.

Tyene then gives him the antidote, but only after he tells her she is the most beautiful woman in the world.

So their power is simply that they are well trained in combat and, like [Oberyn](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Oberyn_Martell), often coat their weapons in poison.